# In such a graph there two adjacent edges, s.t. their removal preserves connectivity

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Let $G$ be a connected graph s.t. no two nodes of degree 1 share a neighbour.

Show:

In this graph there are two adjacent edges, s.t. you can remove them and your resulting graph still has only one non-trivial component.

We even have proved a bunch of interesting properties for graphs. (Say correlations of the numbers of edges and vertices, also equivalent statements to being a tree..) It seems to me that this should be a relatively easy consequence of them. But I have no good idea. Maybe one can reformulate the problem so that its a little clearer...

Any ideas/hints are appreciated! :)

Comment: I think it is implicit from the words *still connected* that $G$ was connected. Should be good to specify beforehand. But consider the path graph $P_n\; | \; n\geq 4$ for example. Any removal makes it disconnected even though it satisfies your conditions?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph

Comment: @Ettore: What abou the end-vertices of a path that has the length of the diameter of $G$? Ich we delete those: does this disconnect $G$?

Comment: Another example is any cycle graph. All its vertices have degree 2, so removing two adjacent edges will always give you a disconnected vertex of degree 0.

Comment: @highgardener thanks a lot. Yes thats true!..I thought I should prove this...I am confused now...@Tortoise : thanks...I have to think about it, that sounds like a good idea...@Jaap Scherphuis: thank you too! Thats again a counterexample...strange...I expected this to be provable...I have to think about it and get back later..